# Как после выполнения процедуры получить результаты в count и arr

Tags: pascal

```
procedure putFor(count:integer; arr:Array of DB_Row);
    var
    num,i:integer;
    s:string;
    temp: Array[0..100] of DB_Row;
    begin
        Writeln('put el num:');
        readln(num);
        Writeln('thank you, and put row');
        Readln(s);

        for i:=1 to count do
        begin
            if i <= num then
            temp[i] := arr[i];
            if i = num then
            temp[i+1] := parse(s);
            if i > num then
            temp[i+1] := arr[i];
        end;

        count:=count+1; 

    end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй определить параметры как var:

```
procedure putFor(var count: integer; var arr: Array of DB_Row);
```

Comment: не прокатит count объявлен но не меняется, хотя нет все сработало как увидел правку ответа

Comment: А это ли не изменение count:=count+1